# Variable inside variable with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a select statement with a dynamic `where` clause taken from a database table and containing a variable that needs to be replaced by the value of this variable also taken from a database table.

```
DECLARE 
    @SelectStatement nvarchar(max),
    @BCPCommand varchar(8000),
    @WhereClause nvarchar(250),
    @WhereValue nvarchar(50)

SELECT @SelectStatement = SELECTSTATEMENT,  @WhereClause = WHERECLAUSE 
FROM [table1] 
WHERE ID =  @ID

SELECT @WhereValue = WHEREVARIABLEVALUE 
FROM [table2] 
WHERE ID = @ID

IF (NOT @WhereClause IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @SelectStatement = @SelectStatement + ' WHERE (' + @WhereClause + ')'
END

SET @BCPCommand = 'BCP "' + @SelectStatement + '" queryout C:\temp\test.txt -T -c /t"|"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @BCPCommand
```

The `@WhereClause` would contain for instance

```
STARTDATE > @WhereValue OR MODIFICATIONDATE > @WhereValue
```

The `@WhereValue` for instance "2020-06-21".

The `@SelectStatement` for instance

```
SELECT * FROM DummyTable
```

How to get the value of the WHEREVARIABLEVALUE in the WHERECLAUSE so the `@SelectStatement` will become:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DummyTable 
WHERE STARTDATE > '2020-06-21' OR MODIFICATIONDATE > '2020-06-21'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a quick REPLACE() call to replace the inner variable.

```
IF (NOT @WhereClause IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = REPLACE(@WhereClause,'@WhereValue',Char(39) + @WhereValue + Char(39))
    SET @SelectStatement = @SelectStatement + ' WHERE (' + @WhereClause + ')'
END
```

Comment: Thank you JMabee for the simple clean solution. Works perfectly